# Crosscompiling C to MIPS64 and simulating

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mips64

I needed to translate the follwing C code to MIPS64:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    for (x=0;x<10;x++) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used codebench to crosscompile this code to MIPS64. The following code was created:

```
    .file   1 "loop.c"
    .section .mdebug.abi32
    .previous
    .gnu_attribute 4, 1
    .abicalls
    .option pic0
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .set    nomips16
    .set    nomicromips
    .ent    main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    .frame  $fp,24,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 1/0, args= 0, gp= 8
    .mask   0x40000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-24
    sw  $fp,20($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $0,8($fp)
    j   $L2
    nop

$L3:
    lw  $2,8($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,8($fp)
$L2:
    lw  $2,8($fp)
    slt $2,$2,10
    bne $2,$0,$L3
    nop

    move    $2,$0
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $fp,20($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,24
    j   $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    main
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Sourcery CodeBench 2012.03-81) 4.6.3"
```

To check if the code works as expected, I usually use the WINMIPS64 simulator. For one or other reason this simulator does not want to accept this code. It appears that every line of code is wrong. I have been looking at this issue for over a day. I hope someone can help me out with this. What is wrong with this assembly code for the mips64 architecture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From page 7 of the WINMIPS64 [documentation](http://indigo.ie/~mscott/winmipstut.docx):

```
The following assembler directives are supported

.data                 - start of data segment
.text                 - start of code segment
.code                 - start of code segment (same as .text)  
.org    <n>           - start address
.space  <n>           - leave n empty bytes
.asciiz <s>           - enters zero terminated ascii string
.ascii  <s>           - enter ascii string
.align  <n>           - align to n-byte boundary
.word   <n1>,<n2>..   - enters word(s) of data (64-bits)
.byte   <n1>,<n2>..   - enter bytes
.word32 <n1>,<n2>..   - enters 32 bit number(s)
.word16 <n1>,<n2>..   - enters 16 bit number(s)
.double <n1>,<n2>..   - enters floating-point number(s)
```

Get rid of everything that's not in the above list, as it won't run in the simulator.

You'll need to move the `.align` to before `.text`

WINMIPS64 expects `daddi`/`daddui` instead of `addi`/`addiu`, again as per the documentation.

As per the documentation, `move $a, $b` is not a supported mnemonic. Replace them with `daddui $a, $b, 0` instead.

`slt` needs to be `slti`.

Finally, the simulator expects an absolute address for `j`, but you've given it a register. Use `jr` instead.

At this point I get an infinite loop. This is because the stack pointer doesn't get initialized. The simulator only gives you 0x400 bytes of memory, so go ahead and initialize the stack to 0x400:

```
.text
    daddui  $sp,$0,0x400
```

*Now* it runs. Since you're running the code by itself, nothing will be in the return register and the final `jr $31` will just bring it back to the beginning.

Here's my version:

```
    .align   2
    .text
    daddui   $sp,$0,0x400
main:
    daddui   $sp,$sp,-24
    sw       $fp,20($sp)
    daddui   $fp,$sp,0
    sw       $0,8($fp)
    j        $L2
    nop

$L3:
    lw       $2,8($fp)
    daddui   $2,$2,1
    sw       $2,8($fp)
$L2:
    lw       $2,8($fp)
    slti     $2,$2,10
    bne      $2,$0,$L3
    nop

    daddui   $2,$0,0
    daddui   $sp,$fp,0
    lw       $fp,20($sp)
    daddui   $sp,$sp,24
    jr       $31
    nop
```

Consider getting either another compiler or another simulator, because these two clearly hate each other.

Comment: Thanks a thousand times. I changed the file with your suggestions but now the simulator hangs on the lines 4, 13 and 24. Do you know any final touches to be made? Is there another c to mips64 cross compiler? 
        .align 2 
 .text
 daddui  $sp,$0,0x400
main:
 daddiu $sp,$sp,-24
 sw $fp,20($sp)
 daddui $fp,$sp,0
 sw $0,8($fp)
 jr $L2
 nop

$L3:
 lw $2,8($fp)
 daddiu $2,$2,1
 sw $2,8($fp)
$L2:
 lw $2,8($fp)
 slt $2,$2,10
 bne $2,$0,$L3
 nop

 daddui $2,$0,0
 daddui $sp,$fp,0
 lw $fp,20($sp)
 daddiu $sp,$sp,24
 jr $31
 nop

Comment: Those lines still have `daddiu` instead of `daddui`.

Comment: Thanks JeFF! I changed it and checked the code with asm.exe Unfortunately there are 17 error on the second pass.

Comment: I've added my version to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code: I saved it in a separate .s file and ran it through asm.exe. The terminal gives me the following message, so does WINMIPS64: ''Pass 2 completed with 16 errors''

Comment: Weird, it works fine for me in both. I guess it wouldn't hurt to re-download WINMIPS64 (mine is v1.57) Does it assemble any of the opcodes as 00000000 (not counting the `nop`s)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17965/discussion-between-alex-van-rijs-and-jeff-e)

Comment: @JeffE I am doing something similar: using Clang/LLVM to cross-compile to MIPS64 assembly.  I want to write the assembler/simulator myself for purposes of dynamic semantic analysis.  Documentation on the MIPS64 instructions is easy to find, but I am mystified by the number of directives for which I cannot find documentation.  Your solutions suggests that many can be ignored.  As you know MIPS64 assembly so well I think it would be very helpful to me if I could have a few minutes of your time to discuss this odd phenomenon of assembly language.